# Auto Complete json associative property

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, autocomplete

im using jquery ui to create a auto complete input box. The input box works well when i only had one property (uk postcode), but than i wanted to add another associative value for my postcode property (town), and the idea was when someone typed the postcode number it appears in the list the name of the town that is pointing, but the jquery code isnt working now.

Json Output:

```
{"AB10":"Aberdeen ","AB11":"Aberdeen ","AB12":"Aberdeen "}
```

PHP:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM uk_postcodes";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection));

    $dname_list = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
       $dname_list[$row['postcode']] = $row['town'];
    }
    echo json_encode($dname_list);
```

html:

```
<input type="text" name="Location" id="uk_postcode" placeholder="town or postcode" value=""/>
```

Jquery:

```
 $(function() {
            var uktowns = <?php include('autocomplete.php'); ?>;
            $("#uk_postcode").autocomplete({
                source: uktowns,
                autoFocus:true
            });
        });
```

Comment: I take it the autocomplete `source:` supports json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Based off the documents, the data needs to be formatted as an array of objects, not just a plain object

http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source

```
[ { label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }, { label: "Choice2", value: "value2" } ]
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

I would try to add this in your php script...

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

Right before....

```
echo json_encode($dname_list);
```

That way when you include the file, it is definitely json.

Comment: thanks for noticing this, but still doesnt answer my question :)